# Using multiple classes to control a character

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to create a virtual pet/basic Sims type game.
I am to use independent class files and call them in the main game file.
I am trying to write a class to control my character and I can add it to the stage, but cannot for the life of me make it move.
I have just spent 4 hours watching tutorials, reading books and just cannot see what I am missing.
Can anyone offer me some advice on getting this to work?
Here is my code ...

This is my main class ...

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import MainCharacter;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Tamagotchi extends MovieClip {

        public function Tamagotchi() {
            var item:MainCharacter = new MainCharacter();
            addChild(item);
            item.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, item.KeyPressListener);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the character class ...

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class MainCharacter extends MovieClip {

        var soph: MovieClip = new SophRun;

        public function MainCharacter() {
            addChild(soph);
            soph.x = 200;
            soph.y = 300;      
            soph.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressListener);
        }

        public function KeyPressListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (e.keyCode == 65)
            {
                soph.x -= 2;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 68)
            {
                soph.x += 2;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 87)
            {
                soph.y -= 2;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 83)
            {
                soph.y += 2;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have moved the eventlistener to multiple places and still cannot get it working.
I am guessing I am missing something obvious, but cannot figure out what!

Comment: Fun project - in addition to the answer below, are you creating an instance of `Tamagotchi` and adding it to the stage? One thing to get in the habit of is to use `trace()` statements as a diagnostic when you want to check if something is happening – key events, etc. getting triggered, etc. Also, make quick test movies if there are methods and functions you haven't used before - learn in those and then apply to your project.

Comment: Yeah, I can get the character on the stage but still cannot get it to move! I am stumped.
I have tried using the instance name, using `.this` at the start and even using `stage.` at the start. Nothing. Not a thing.
I just don't understand it.

Comment: And yeah, I added a trace statement to the keyPressListener function and still nothing. It is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `KeyboardEvent` listener to the stage - currently it'll only work if your character has text focus, which it won't ever have.

A simple setup that I like, it to have an `Input` class, that adds the necessary event listeners and you can then use to check if keys are pressed. Something like:

```
public class Input
{
    // handy constants for common keys
    public static const A:int = 65;
    public static const B:int = 66;
    ...
    public static const LEFT:int = 37;
    public static const UP:int = 38;
    public static const RIGHT:int = 39;
    public static const DOWN:int = 40;

    private var m_keysPressed:Vector.<Boolean> = null; // the keys currently pressed

    public function Input( stage:Stage )
    {
        // we create our vector for the max number of keys that we're going to support (standard keyboard)
        this.m_keysPressed = new Vector.<Boolean>( 225, true );

        // add our listeners
        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this._onKeyDown );
        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, this._onKeyUp );
    }

    public function isKeyPressed( key:int ):Boolean
    {
        if( key < 0 || key >= this.m_keysPressed.length )
            return false;
        return this.m_keysPressed[key];
    }

    private function _onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void

        this.m_keysPressed[e.keyCode] = true;
    }

    private function _onKeyUp( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {
        this.m_keysPressed[e.keyCode] = false;
    }
}
```

This way, all your input code is central. You can then call it via:

```
if( myInput.isKeyPressed( Input.UP ) )
    // move up
```

The benefits:

- Your code is central - easy to change
- Easy to disable or enable (pause functionality)
- You can add simple callbacks (`Dictionary` with `int` key and `Function` value)
- You can add methods like `justPressed( key )` or `justReleased( key )` easily
- You don't get the problem of repeating keys (when a key is held down, Flash will repeat the `KEY_DOWN` event)

You might need to add bounds checks for the `_onKeyDown()` and `_onKeyUp()` functions if you plan to use this on mobile though, as the Android Home and Back keys have stupidly high `keyCode` values.

NOTE: if it's still not working, make sure you've given the stage focus (i.e. clicked on it), and you're not in a `TextField` etc (`stage.focus = null`)

Comment: To be honest, that confused me! I am really new to this and that was a lot of code I haven't even learned yet and don't fully understand.
I want to understand and then use the code, I would feel like a cheat just copying what you showed me but I really do appreciate it. I will keep it marked for future reference when I fully understand it. :)

Comment: Basically it's doing what you're doing, except that it's in a dedicated class that simplifies life for you. Rather than add event listeners everywhere, you just need to call `isKeyPressed( key )`. In general, one event listener in a central place is better than multiple event listeners (you can follow the same principle for your enter frame events with an `Update` class)

Comment: Those handy constants can be found in the Keyboard class.